# My DNN return the same prediction for all test data (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, regression, deep-learning

I am trying to run this code on my data for regression. It seems the the network can predict the first test data but all other predictions are the same as the first one. The first function generates random weights for initialization. The number of predictors is 54 and the number of outputs is 4. Here is my code:

```
def init_weights(shape):
   weights = tf.random_uniform(shape, -2,2)
   return tf.Variable(weights)

def forwardprop(X, w, b, sig):
   if sig==1:
       yhat = tf.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(X, w),b))
   else:
       yhat = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, w),0.)
return yhat

def main(itr,starter_learning_rate):    

   x_size = train_X.shape[1]  
   h_size = 4
   y_size = train_y.shape[1]  

   X = tf.placeholder("float", shape = [None, x_size])
   y = tf.placeholder("float", shape = [None, y_size])

   w_1 = init_weights((x_size, h_size))
   b_1 =  tf.constant(1.)

   w_2 = init_weights((h_size, y_size))
   b_2 =  tf.constant(1.)

   yhat_1 = forwardprop(X, w_1, b_1, 1)    
   yhat =  forwardprop(yhat_1, w_2, b_2, 0)


   n_samples = train_X.shape[0]
   cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(yhat-y, 2))/(2*n_samples)
   updates = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(starter_learning_rate).minimize(cost)


   sess = tf.Session()
   init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
   sess.run(init)

   for epoch in range(itr):
       sess.run(updates, feed_dict={X: train_X, y: train_y})
       train_err = train_y - sess.run(yhat, feed_dict={X: train_X, y: train_y})
       train_accuracy = np.mean(train_err**2)

       test_err  = test_y - sess.run(yhat, feed_dict={X: test_X, y: test_y})
       test_accuracy  =np.mean(test_err**2)


   print(sess.run(yhat, feed_dict={X: test_X, y: test_y}))
   sess.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main(itr=10000,starter_learning_rate=0.001)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalization of the label vector was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

check the data of test_X, maybe all records of text_X is same.